Postbuild command in elastic beanstalk doesn't work but command works when ssh into EC2 instance
In my current setup, I have a django backend running in Elastic Beanstalk and a private RDS instance using mysql engine.
When I deploy, I want to migrate any migrations that haven't been migrated yet.
This is the config file in my .ebextensions:
container_commands:
  01_migrate:
    command: "source /var/app/venv/*/bin/activate && python3 /var/app/current/python/manage.py migrate --noinput"
    leader_only: true

This deploys successfully, but when I check the logs it gives me this output:
[INFO] Command 01_migrate
[INFO] -----------------------Command Output-----------------------
[INFO]  Operations to perform:
[INFO]    Apply all migrations: admin, app, auth, contenttypes, sessions
[INFO]  Running migrations:
[INFO]    No migrations to apply.

It says no migrations to apply when there are migrations that haven't been applied yet.
I ran the same exact command after I ssh into the EC2 instance for my EB application and it applied the migrations successfully.
I can't troubleshoot what the problem may be.

one reasons could be the leader_only marker - as explained here if you have replaced your beanstalk with another one then the leader marker won't be set and thus this script won't be run. For your script you anyways don't need and therefore I would simply remove it.

@JAsgarov the script obviously ran, as evidenced by the script's output log that is included in the question. Also the accepted answer on the question you linked specifically talks about using leader_only for database migration scripts. The official documentation https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html#linux-container-commands even has an example of using leader_only for a Django deployment's migration script, just like in the question.
